# Wildfly Access to 127.0.0.1 was denied shows when accessing Java 11 spring boot deployed app

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, wildfly, web-deployment

I have followed [this guide](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) to deploy the spring boot application in wildfly version 23.0.2 Final. War file is successfully deployed.
But when I try to access through context root it shows Access to 127.0.0.1 was denied error.
What am I missing ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` ? Java spring applications usually run on 8080 port

Comment: Yes, it redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ port only, there only I am getting authorization error.

Comment: Auth error means the url is not open for open access i.e., it needs login (auth token). If you have used spring security in your pom.xml then I would say you need to allow access to `/` and `/hello` by configuring web security part. Study about it more.

Comment: I have not added spring security dependency.

Comment: Show us the code